# Gravity Forms and Gravity View Permissions

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, permissions, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a pretty direct question. I am trying to figure out how to programmatically prevent users from being able to view other users' form submissions. Currently, using Gravity View, any logged in user can look at the URL and just start incrementally changing the number to see anyone's form submissions.

Apparently Gravity Kit offers an addon for this, but I would prefer to do this programmatically. Thoughts?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the entry slug a hash instead of incrementing using this filter:

```
add_filter( 'gravityview_custom_entry_slug', '__return_true' );
```

For limiting visibility, I recommend the Advanced Filtering extension.